# Do we need to use root = None during in the function? (python BST, reference counting)

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, reference-counting

I am practicing deleting node in BST and came across the following code.

```
def deleteNode(root, key):

    if root is None:
        return root

    if key < root.key:
        root.left = deleteNode(root.left, key)

    elif(key > root.key):
        root.right = deleteNode(root.right, key)

    else:
        if root.left is None:
            temp = root.right
            root = None
            return temp

        elif root.right is None:
            temp = root.left
            root = None
            return temp

        temp = minValueNode(root.right)
        root.key = temp.key
        root.right = deleteNode(root.right, temp.key)

    return root
```

My question is do we need the line of root = None? According to reference counting, I feel root will be automatically destroyed as the only reference like parent.child is detached. Any explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is from [moronsformorons](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-2-delete/), right? Just one more example of how absolutely terrible that site is.

Comment: No, those lines make no sense and don't do anything useful given that they are followed by an unconditional `return`

Comment: @KellyBundy Yeah it is from the link. Other than those lines I personally feel the rest code is well written. If you have a better site in mind, recommendation is appreciated

Comment: Yes, other than that nonsense and the unnecessary and inconsistent parentheses, this code seems alright. But that nonsense alone is infuriating enough. Should just be `return root.right` instead of those three lines. They even did do that in the Java code. And they do such bad stuff all the time, by now I *expect* to be appalled when someone leads me there.

Comment: @KellyBundy Thanks for the helpful reply. Code in leetcode solutions generally has better quality, but this website comes in handy when I want a quick comparison on my code with others. As I said, if you have better suggestions on sources, that would greatly help beginners like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `root = None` is immediately followed by `return temp`, it is just (re-)binding a local variable that is immediately discarded again and has no effect whatsoever.

In the given code, the lines `root = None` can be removed without changing the result of running the code.

Presumably the code was translated too literally from a different language where assigning to a variable changes the contents of a memory location.

But in Python, the assignment operator `=` just binds a new name<sup>1</sup> to an already existing object (in this case it gives the name `root` to the object `None`) and does not change the object or any other object in memory.

---

<sup>1</sup> at least with "simple names" on the left-hand side, it is a bit more complicated when assigning to something like `a[i]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So just to clarify, that line of code is redundant right (totally agree it does not change the result, but efficiency-wise is that the same too? Looks to me the code tries to empty the memory space, which I feel reference counting will automatically do the job)

Comment: In the C++ and C versions they wrote `free(root);` there, so yes, most certainly a bad translation by someone clueless. Interestingly, in the Java version they didn't do that nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

No, those lines aren't necessary. If you removed the early return in either branch, however, then you would need to set `root = None`.

Comment: In a version without those `return`s, what would `root = None` achieve?

Comment: It'd change the return value on the last line. But the algorithm likely wouldn't be correct at that point.

Comment: Yes, returning `None` would often be wrong. But it wouldn't even get that far, as the `root.right` would right away give an error.